# Upgrading Tapestry application from 5.0.18 to 5.3.2

Tags: java, javascript, tapestry

I'm upgrading my app from 5.0.18 to 5.3.2 and i get following error. Have made couple of changes and not sure which one causing this error. Nothing from logs. This error pops up on the UI. Following are the changes done.

- Changed `@IncludeStylesheet` and `@IncludeJavaScriptLibrary` to `@Import`
- Changed `RenderSupport` to `JavaScriptSupport`
- Changed `@ApplicationState` to `@SessionState`

I get following error in the UI.

```
Function Tapestry.Initializer.activate() does not exist.
Function Tapestry.Initializer.formEventManager() does not exist
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as a caching problem. Clear your cache and see if it persists. Otherwise it sounds like you have some custom javascript or javascript from a third party tapestry component laying around that was developed around Tapesty.js of version 5.0.18. Check out the javascript stacktrace on the error and see where the call originates and update the js code.

Comment: I did clear the browser cache and didn't help. I noticed we use http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd on some of the pages. Do i need to upgrade the xsd also to http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd?

Comment: Do update your xsd to the current version but it's very unlikely that is in any way linked to your problem. Do some javascript debugging on the line where you are seeing the error, check the call stack and see where the call originates and fix it or post it here.

Comment: Did javascript debugging and could see tapestry.js of version 5.0.18 is loaded. This could be the problem. Trying to figure out how this is loaded as all 5.0.18 jar files have been removed.

Comment: Could see tapestry.js of version 5.0.18  is loaded from build path. Removed and error gone. Thanks for your help.